# Get the object_id of the sub-document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The schema of my model is:-

```
var socialSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  friend_names:[String],
  friend_pics:[String],
  friend_id:[String],
  friend_requests:[String],
  friend_req_profilepic:[String]

})


var userSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
    },
    username: {
      type: String,
      index:true
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,

    },

      profileimage:{
        type:String
    },

    friends:{
      type:Number
    },

    social:[socialSchema]


  })
```

This is the Mongoose Query i am making:-(Here frname and frpic are the friend_requests and friend_req_profilepic values in the socialschema)

```
module.exports.friendAccept= function(req, res){
  var frname= req.body.username;
  var frpic = req.body.userpic;
  var user= req.user;
  User
  .findOne({name:user.name})
  .select('social')
  .exec(function(err,doc){
    console.log(doc)
  })
}
```

The output of the above console log is :-

```
{ _id: 5bc6c85305c18b5a646d0fdb,
  social:
   [ { friend_names: [],
       friend_pics: [],
       friend_id: [],
       friend_requests: [Array],
       friend_req_profilepic: [Array],
       _id: 5bc723fbc002735ae4c380aa },
     { friend_names: [Array],
       friend_pics: [Array],
       friend_id: [],
       friend_requests: [],
       friend_req_profilepic: [],
       _id: 5bc72421c002735ae4c380ab } ] }
```

The above values of frname and frpic belongs to one of these documents. So how can i able to get the _id of the sub-document which stores these two values

Comment: You are requires to get `_id: 5bc723fbc002735ae4c380aa` and `_id: 5bc72421c002735ae4c380ab` etc?

Comment: Not exactly, i need to get one of them, whose friend_requests holds the value frname and friend_req_profilepic holds the value of frpic

Comment: can You please update `friend_requests ` and `friend_req_profilepic ` with sample data?

Comment: friend_requests holds the array of strings (user names) and friend_rep_profilepic is an array of strings which stores the name of their profilepic (as stores in database)